# files add before after running server

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.11

When i run python manage.py runserver 8000

one file fuzzy.xml comes first and when I delete that file from that directory it sends error

```
/home/yelesee/Desktop/Mirab/Mirab/web/data/fuzzy.xml
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
September 05, 2018 - 06:51:30
Django version 1.11, using settings 'Mirab.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C
```

and the last line of error is

```
File "/home/yelesee/anaconda3/envs/venv/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 647, in parse
    source = open(source, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/yelesee/Desktop/Mirab/Mirab/web/data/fuzzy.xml'
```

I don't know where to search and remove that from code.
where should I find that?

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7f2c20bbca28>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yelesee/anaconda3/envs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/yelesee/anaconda3/envs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/yelesee/anaconda3/envs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/yelesee/anaconda3/envs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/yelesee/anaconda3/envs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/yelesee/anaconda3/envs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/yelesee/anaconda3/envs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/home/yelesee/anaconda3/envs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 254, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/yelesee/anaconda3/envs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/yelesee/anaconda3/envs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/yelesee/anaconda3/envs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/yelesee/anaconda3/envs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/home/yelesee/anaconda3/envs/venv/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/yelesee/Desktop/Mirab/Mirab/Mirab/urls.py", line 26, in <module>
    ]  + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
  File "/home/yelesee/anaconda3/envs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 50, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/home/yelesee/anaconda3/envs/venv/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/yelesee/Desktop/Mirab/Mirab/web/urls.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/home/yelesee/Desktop/Mirab/Mirab/web/views.py", line 25, in <module>
    from lists import *
  File "/home/yelesee/Desktop/Mirab/Mirab/web/lists.py", line 6, in <module>
    tree = et.parse(xml_file)
  File "/home/yelesee/anaconda3/envs/venv/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1182, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "/home/yelesee/anaconda3/envs/venv/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 647, in parse
    source = open(source, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/yelesee/Desktop/Mirab/Mirab/web/data/fuzzy.xml'
```

Comment: Please show the *full* error not just the last lines. Presumably something in your own code is trying to load that XML files.

Comment: Could you please show the details of error and what are the django app installed. Which will be easy to reproduce

Comment: i edit the post with detail

Comment: `File "/home/yelesee/Desktop/Mirab/Mirab/web/lists.py", line 6, in <module>
    tree = et.parse(xml_file)` seems the problematic line, with `xml_file` being the file missing.